# Issue with pivot_longer command

Tags: r, panel-data

I am trying to convert a long dataset to a wide set set using pivot longer, the column headers are "Program ID" and ‘Participant_Count_22’, ‘Participant_Count_21’, ‘Participant_Count_20’, ‘Participant_Count_19’ for four years 2019-2022.

```
   program_tot %>% pivot_longer(cols=c(‘Participant_Count_22’, ‘Participant_Count_21’, ‘Participant_Count_20’, ‘Participant_Count_19’), 
               names_to='year',
               values_to='Participant_Count')
```

I am getting an unexpected input error message. Any tips?

Comment: You seem to have fancy single quotes around your column names. Try converting them to normal single quotes, or to normal double quotes. Or even try `cols = -1` to pivot all columns except the first

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have fancy single quotes around your column names. Note carefully the difference between quotes in `‘Participant_Count_22’`, which R doesn't recognise as a string, and `'Participant_Count_22'`, which it *does* recognise as a string.

In any case, you will save yourself some time and complexity if you use the selection helpers to select columns. In your case you could use `contains("Participant_Count")`

```r
library(tidyverse)

program_tot %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("Participant_Count"),
               names_to = 'year',
               values_to = 'Participant_Count') %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(paste0("20", sub("Participant_Count_", "", year))))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#>    Program.ID  year Participant_Count
#>    <fct>      <dbl>             <dbl>
#>  1 1           2022                 5
#>  2 1           2021                 5
#>  3 1           2020                 6
#>  4 1           2019                 2
#>  5 2           2022                 7
#>  6 2           2021                 2
#>  7 2           2020                 8
#>  8 2           2019                 5
#>  9 3           2022                 4
#> 10 3           2021                 8
#> 11 3           2020                 1
#> 12 3           2019                 7
#> 13 4           2022                 3
#> 14 4           2021                 1
#> 15 4           2020                 3
#> 16 4           2019                 3
#> 17 5           2022                 5
#> 18 5           2021                 3
#> 19 5           2020                 2
#> 20 5           2019                 1
```

---

**Data used**

```r
program_tot <- data.frame('Program ID' = factor(1:5),
                           Participant_Count_22 = c(5, 7, 4, 3, 5), 
                           Participant_Count_21 = c(5, 2, 8, 1, 3), 
                           Participant_Count_20 = c(6, 8, 1, 3, 2), 
                           Participant_Count_19 = c(2, 5, 7, 3, 1))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>